# How do you pause a Laravel queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a queue that sends requests to a remote service. Sometimes this service undergoes a maintenance. I want all queue tasks to pause and retry in 10 minutes when such situation is encountered. How do I implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use ...

class SendRequest implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    const REMOTE_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE = 'remote_server_unavailable';

    private $msg;
    private $retryAfter;

    public function __construct($msg)
    {
        $this->msg = $msg;
        $this->retryAfter = 10;
    }

    /**
    * Execute the job.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function handle(){
        try {
            // if we have tried sending the request and get a RemoteServerException, we will
            // redispatch the job directly and return.
            if(Cache::get(self::REMOTE_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE)) {
                self::dispatch($this->msg)->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes($this->retryAfter));
                return;                  
            }
            // send request to remote server
            // ...
        } catch (RemoteServerException $e) {
            // set a cache value expires in 10 mins if not exists.
            Cache::add(self::REMOTE_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE,'1', $this->retryAfter);
            // if the remote service undergoes a maintenance, redispatch a new delayed job.
            self::dispatch($this->msg)->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes($this->retryAfter));            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But in that case all jobs would be hitting the server. For example if I have 1000 jobs in queue, all of them will try to make a request every 10 minutes. What I want is that if 1 job gets maintenance exception it should pause all others.

Comment: Hi Poma, sorry for late. I have edited my answer, please check. We can't pause the queue, but we can use some global variable (e.g. variable in redis) to stop sending the reqeust when we already know the remote server is unavailable.

Comment: Great idea! This will avoid unnecessary requests

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `Queue::looping()` event listener to pause an entire queue or connection (not just an individual job class). Unlike other methods, this will *not* put each job in a cycle of pop/requeue while the queue is paused, meaning **the number of attempts will not increase**.

Here's what the docs say:

> Using the `looping` method on the `Queue` facade, you may specify
> callbacks that execute before the worker attempts to fetch a job from
> a queue.
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-events

What this *doesn't* document very well is that if the callback returns `false` then [the worker will not fetch another job](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e5a8b2d/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L175). For example, this will prevent the `default` queue from running:

```
Queue::looping(function (\Illuminate\Queue\Events\Looping $event) {
    // $event->connectionName (e.g. "database")
    // $event->queue (e.g. "default")

    if ($event->queue == 'default') {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note: The `queue` property of the event will contain the value from the command line when the worker process was started, so if your worker was checking more than one queue (e.g. `artisan queue:work --queue=high,default`) then the value of `queue` in the event will be `'high,default'`. As a precaution, you may instead want to explode the string by commas and check if `default` is in the list.

So for example, if you want to create a rudimentary [circuit breaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern) to pause the `mail` queue when your mail service returns a maintenance error, then you can register a listener like this in your **EventServiceProvider.php**:

```
/**
 * Register any events for your application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Queue::looping(function (\Illuminate\Queue\Events\Looping $event) {
        if (($event->queue == 'mail') && (cache()->get('mail-queue-paused'))) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

This assumes you have a mechanism somewhere else in your application to detect the appropriate situation and, in this example, that mechanism would need to assign a value to the `mail-queue-paused` key in the shared cache (because that's what my code is checking for). There are much more robust solutions, but setting a specific well-known key in the cache (and expiring it automatically) is simple and achieves the desired effect.